# Populating a UITableView with plist dictonary

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Been slowly picking up the basics in IOS Programming, but seemed to have hit a small hurdle

I have a table that gets populated from a plist located on a webserver

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Item 0</key>
<dict>
    <key>eventDate</key>
    <string>27-06-2012</string>
    <key>eventTitle</key>
    <string>Clinic</string>
</dict>
<key>Item 1</key>
<dict>
    <key>eventDate</key>
    <string>28-06-2012</string>
    <key>eventTitle</key>
    <string>Clinic</string>
</dict>
<key>Item 2</key>
<dict>
    <key>eventDate</key>
    <string>28-06-2012</string>
    <key>eventTitle</key>
    <string>Office Closed</string>
</dict>
<key>Item 3</key>
<dict>
    <key>eventDate</key>
    <string>29-06-2012</string>
    <key>eventTitle</key>
    <string>Tour</string>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now after doing a punt load of reading I have managed to hack together this code to populate a Table.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
UITableViewCell * cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if (nil == cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
            reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}

NSString *currentEventName;
currentEventName = [eventKey_web objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[[cell textLabel] setText:currentEventName];

return cell;
}

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL * myURL1;

myURL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/events.plist"];

event_web = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL1];
eventKey_web = [event_web allKeys];
}
```

Now my table is populating but only with Item 0, Item 1, Item 2

My goal is to populate the table with eventTitle as the description.

Sorry for the possibly dumb question but still trying to get my head around Objective C

Comment: have you tried NSLog your event_web to see if you have all the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the NSDictionary by your key in the function, and retrieve the corresponding data from your dictionary.

```
NSString *currentEventName = [eventKey_web objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  // This is only the key from your root dict
NSDictionary *currentEventDict = [event_web objectForKey:currentEventName];
NSString *currentEventDate = [currentEventDict objectForKey:@"eventDate"];
NSString *currentEventTitle = [currentEventDict objectForKey:@"eventTitle"];

//  Here do what you need to show
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`eventKey_web = [event_web allKeys];` get all keys from your plist, you need to add value for that key..

So instead of using this:

`currentEventName = [eventKey_web objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

You can use something like :

```
NSMutableDictionary *r = [[event_web objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:[eventKey_web objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ];
event_web = [r objectForKey:@"eventTitle"]`
```