# prepareForSegue and populating from a pList File

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a prepareForSegue that should pass information from one page to another, however i know i have missed a line somewhere that is causing me greif

Basically its calling a plist file from the internet that populates a tableview controller, when you select the value its supposed to go from one page to a new page with more information

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    EventsViewController *evc1 = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    Events *d = [eventKey_web objectAtIndex:[path row]];
    [evc1 setCurrentEvent:d];
}
```

For a sample of my plist file can be found here [Populating a UITableView with plist dictonary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188049/populating-a-uitableview-with-plist-dictonary)

If i do a

```
NSLog(@"Event ID = %@",currentEvent);
```

in my EventViewController page I get the correct output of Item X but for the life of me i can't seem to work out how to pass the eventDates and eventTitles across.

I know its only going to be one line but if anyone could give me a gentle nudge in the right direction this would be awesome

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is.  It looks like your question was answered in your other post that you referenced. The accepted answer there shows you how to get the eventDates and eventTitles

Comment: The main issue is want to change to text labels of eventDate and eventTitles in my EventViewController. Anything I try seems to result in Xcode giving errors or my app crashing when I try and load it

Comment: So, have you tried adding this, and see what you get:
NSDictionary *dict = [event_web objectForKey:d];
NSLog(@"Event Date = %@", [dict objectForKey:@"eventDate"];)
NSLog(@"Event Title = %@", [dict objectForKey:@"eventTitle"]);